# Keycloak JWT offline valiadation

Tags: keycloak

so I want to implement the offline validation of keycloak JWT token. The offline validation happens by taking the signature part of the JWT token and applying server's public key to validate the signature. The process is described [here](http://www.janua.fr/keycloak-access-token-verification-example/).

However I am facing an issue, that tokens created by keycloak cannot be verified by the use of the server's public key. For quick validation I use this [service](https://jwt.io/).

So here is my example:

I authenticated to keycloak and obtained an access token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJMdTZNY1h4M3ZOeVkydjVwREpDMVBFaUpUUjJSbmc0S0lrSG54NnBtUjNjIn0.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.douJsDyObXAKylBexZCTQvEU5v3OY5xJtfNxnUhwDpIOoN1lpw7Tdxwf3jsEWi-ZTKVzV3H1zjhorPCs02tAjjpH9bDQHQmSBtn4R8V2dbXbIedBxK0kl_YfnrYTFPX66lQTpHWoWP9qngxoEqOJcFSnDFnPHwwz774PUZdqPA4FZOwb02LxDtUVKdBfM_bI41LDD2Nsvc_sKuTVuq_dbST3CqjlapAo-Q61vgSoH1zMtCGy9XUBOs1nhyeDhAaGVGcPYD3RwqYuRkfKPl0BuuB_5D8Z1xaEp-1G8M06vMIW0HpESp-NUTUb30rGib5EmAlW3rT6M2_8B6oUUtGhhA
```

The JWT token has been generated with a `kid`: `Lu6McXx3vNyY2v5pDJC1PEiJTR2Rng4KIkHnx6pmR3c`. 
So In my keycloak installation, the key with this ID has public key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgk9p0QOXtnzsQIVviM4kEoIGtewKAqUG9CtlQ6Esd6Z2RMu5qvQb8iBQVvkiFSHXGEd3kJqY3H7KZk+pkFuoQSdsLqGM5UhPeMjk2pIog0n0lXDxcd6Ff8hywmiIgfIWJW5DeDwvGTPLR1BiLPiina2qemACwUk5VCVdRzr2ob712PohcyNIa34PasPI1kBve0ks/wKNZK5vnGDPC6orFlJL48t2e2gB0Lz5rAJ1l2MJ+tV3cXjjB5wh62cWyJ/xYThGsK48vaXciTRVn8/sZRoJA4c+ZLKg28YOry9zHnAO8B+mj17Nj5Chpat6iYv00pqA0lMxiiQeK6yXxT6cswIDAQAB
```

The corresponding certificate:

```
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
```

At this point it looks like the token cannot be validate with neither the key, nor the certificate... Do I need to set some settings in keycloak to enable the offline validation? Or is it an error on the jwt.io service? What is the correct way to offline validate a keycloak jwt token?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue actually was on the jwt.io website. You have to input the public key as follows:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgk9p0QOXtnzsQIVviM4kEoIGtewKAqUG9CtlQ6Esd6Z2RMu5qvQb8iBQVvkiFSHXGEd3kJqY3H7KZk+pkFuoQSdsLqGM5UhPeMjk2pIog0n0lXDxcd6Ff8hywmiIgfIWJW5DeDwvGTPLR1BiLPiina2qemACwUk5VCVdRzr2ob712PohcyNIa34PasPI1kBve0ks/wKNZK5vnGDPC6orFlJL48t2e2gB0Lz5rAJ1l2MJ+tV3cXjjB5wh62cWyJ/xYThGsK48vaXciTRVn8/sZRoJA4c+ZLKg28YOry9zHnAO8B+mj17Nj5Chpat6iYv00pqA0lMxiiQeK6yXxT6cswIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This way the service verifies jwt token correctly.